# Google App Engine, Python and IPython

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ipython

I want to use IPython under GAE to debug scripts locally:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

but GAE restricts loading some modules from sys.path. Can I bypass this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack the GAE SDK's restrictions of course (you *do* have its sources on your computer, and it's open-source code!-), but, if you do, it won't catch the cases in which your code erroneously tries to import modules it won't be allowed to use on Google's servers.  So I suggest, at the very least, if you do perform such a hack, make it conditional on some environment variable (`if os.getenv('MYHACK')=='Y':` ...), so that it's disabled by default (and the GAE SDK behaves normally) and you only enable it explicitly at your shell with e.g.

```
$ MYHACK=Y ipython ...
```

at a `bash` (or `sh`;-) prompt.

Comment: Thanks for answer. May be I will try do it myself, but to be honest I am not very familiar with Python and GAE internals and there is a lot of code to explore. For now I am able just to check sys.path :)

Comment: Alex the answer above doesn't actually show where in the SDK the restrictions are actually implemented. Have you done this successfully? How? Thanks.